# Questions Concerning Arduino Compatible Boards

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, arduino-motor-shield, robotics, electronics

I've seen an Arduino-compatible board called Bluno from DFRobot. I'm curious if a shield, specifically the DFRobot motor shield can be connected to the Bluno.

Can anyone confirm if it can be connected with a shield?

Answer (score 1):

The Bluno is identical to the Uno, except the USB-to-serial chip, also supports BT. So it won't be a problem.